# window.onload if error - statement expected

Tags: javascript, if-statement, window, onload

```
window.onload(
    if(localStorage.getItem('name') !== null) {
        $('#greet').html('Hello ' + localStorage.getItem('name'))
    };
);
```

Why do i get a statement expected error on the if here? Can't i put if-s in window.onload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong this is the write one. Because You should assign function to `window.onload`.
Read the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

```
window.onload = function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('name') !== null) {
    $('#greet').html('Hello ' + localStorage.getItem('name'));
  }
};
```

Comment: A function is how you write some code which can be called later and/or repeatedly. It's a fairly fundamental part of most programming languages.

Comment: window.onload is an event, so you need to create a function to handle that event for it to run.